# Is there a difference in these two sentences?

Tags: meaning, grammar

Are these two sentence equivalent in their meaning, or is there subtle differences because of where the word *who* is placed?

> 1. No one has come forward who remembers seeing Bill that Monday.
> 2. No one who has come forward remembers seeing Bill that Monday.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - the first states that no witnesses have come forward. The second implies that, though some people *have* come forward, they don't include anyone with the required information.

Comment: No useful (in the immediate context) witnesses.

Answer (score 1):

In the first sentence people *may* have come forward: in the second they *have*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. After making the syntactic and semantic analysis, he have that:

**First Sentence:**

Subject: "No-one who remember seeing Bill that Monday"

Predicate: "has come forward"

**Second sentence:**

Subject: "No-one who has come forward"

Predicate: "remembers seeing Bill that Monday"